# Looking for algorithms capable of modifying graph structure

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I realize this is a quite a general request. I'm just looking for examples of path searching algorithms for directed graphs which are capable of utilizing simple modifications (adding vertices, adding edges, deleting edges; all from a set of specific allowed modifications). I've been looking everywhere online for information on dynamic algorithms for graphs, but so far almost everything I've found is almost exclusively concerning run time of such algorithms. Run time is irrelevant to me as there are very few modifications that are allowed to be made in the problem I'm working on. Does anyone know of any algorithms like this?

Answer (score 2):

The best option is without a doubt SageMath. One way of using it is by creating an account on [Sage Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/). I am not quite sure what you mean by dynamic modification but perhaps you could give a concrete example what do you need in case the example bellow is not informative enough.

Quick example

```
sage: G = Graph()
sage: G.add_edge(1,2)
sage: G.add_edge(2,3)
sage: G.add_vertices([7,4,5,6])
sage: G.delete_vertex(7)
sage: G.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like it could be useful, thanks. What I mean by dynamic modification is simply that if a path cannot be found by the algorithm, it has the ability to update the graph and try again (by adding new vertices and edges according to very strict constraints that I won't get into)

Comment: @Will You can most likely make a quick Sage function to do what you want